# Converting dataframe to dataframe in R? Unexpected results

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

I need to do many conversions at once ina certain file I'm running.
I do not understand why converting something twice results in a different output.

given

```
x = c(140,190,190,185,195,195,195,130,150,125,50,30,15,45,55)
y = c(150,195,190,190,190,200,195,140,30,20,125,25,45,65,70)
```

This,

```
locs <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
```

...works as expected, with two columns named x and y.  However, if I do the following

```
locs <- as.data.frame(x=x,y=y)
```

it gives just one column **named**  x, but with the **values** of **y**.  Why is this?  It is important for the larger files I'm running - I may have to change my whole approach.

Comment: What about reading `?as.data.frame` and `?data.frame`? They are two different functions doing two different things. They can't be used interchangeably. In your second line I get one column with `x` values, exactly as expected (again, read the documentation!).

Comment: You don't say which version of R you use. With R-3.2.0 and using `as.data.frame(x=x,y=y)`, I get column "x" with values from vector "x". Anyway, you don't respect the syntax of `as.data.frame`, i.e. first argument is the R object to coerce into data.frame, second argument is the row names. It seems that in my case, `y=y` is just ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.frame` starts of with `...`, which is often populated with "tag/value" pairs to be combined as columns. Thus, `data.frame(x = x, y = y)` would work as you expected.

`as.data.frame` expects a single object that can be coerced into a `data.frame` using one of the `as.data.frame.*` methods. It also has a `...` argument, but this is used to pass arguments to the different `as.data.frame` methods.

In other words, if you had a `matrix` (`m <- cbind(x, y)`), you could use `as.data.frame(m)` and get the results you expected, though if you are starting with vectors, you might as well just do `data.frame(x, y)`.